# Desired image sometimes is not shared in status via Facebook Graph API

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api

I am developing on iOS 4.0(supporting higher versions too).
I am using facebook Graph API, and so far everything works as it should. I can update statuses with images and stuff.
But, there are weird things happening.
I am passing in my FB init class an image link. 
But when the FBDialog appears, sometimes the image is there, and sometimes it's not! And i was debugging for  a whole while, and i can say for sure: in both cases(when it is and when it's not) the link is not just working: it's totally the same. Practically, i can't find any differences in both behaviors. 
What could be the reason? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my appid. not sure exactly what was the problem, but changing it solved it.